# How to parse consecutive tags with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have HTML code like this:

```
<div id="first">
<dt>Label1</dt>
<dd>Value1</dd>

<dt>Label2</dt>
<dd>Value2</dd>

...
</div>
```

My code does not work.

```
doc.css("first").each do |item|
  label = item.css("dt")
  value = item.css("dd")
end
```

Show all the `<dt>` tags firsts and then the `<dd>` tags and I need "label: value"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your HTML should have the `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements inside a `<dl>`:

```
<div id="first">
    <dl>
        <dt>Label1</dt>
        <dd>Value1</dd>
        <dt>Label2</dt>
        <dd>Value2</dd>
        ...
    </dl>
</div>
```

but that won't change how you parse it. You want to find the `<dt>`s and iterate over them, then at each `<dt>` you can use `next_element` to get the `<dd>`; something like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div id="first"><dl>...')
doc.css('#first').search('dt').each do |node|
    puts "#{node.text}: #{node.next_element.text}"
end
```

That should work as long as the structure matches your example.

Comment: Instead of `doc.css('#first').search('dt').each` why not just `doc.css('#first dt').each`? Note also that this answer works under the assumption that there is always one-and-only-one `<dd>` immediately after each `<dt>` (which might not be the case in general HTML).

Comment: @Phrogz: No good reason for `.css.search` other than, perhaps, it is closer to what the OP already has. And I did include a "That should work as long as the structure matches your example" caveat. I'd agree that your approach would work better in a general case. (This is just a spelling correction of my last comment cuz I dun haz gud speling)

Answer (score 6):

Under the assumption that some `<dt>` may have multiple `<dd>`, you want to find all `<dt>` and then (for each) find the following `<dd>` before the next `<dt>`. This is pretty easy to do in pure Ruby, but more fun to do in just XPath. ;)

Given this setup:

```
require 'nokogiri'   
html = '<dl id="first">
  <dt>Label1</dt><dd>Value1</dd>
  <dt>Label2</dt><dd>Value2</dd>
  <dt>Label3</dt><dd>Value3a</dd><dd>Value3b</dd>
  <dt>Label4</dt><dd>Value4</dd>
</dl>'    
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(html)
```

**Using no XPath**:

```
doc.css('dt').each do |dt|
  dds = []
  n = dt.next_element
  begin
    dds << n
    n = n.next_element
  end while n && n.name=='dd'
  p [dt.text,dds.map(&:text)]
end
#=> ["Label1", ["Value1"]]
#=> ["Label2", ["Value2"]]
#=> ["Label3", ["Value3a", "Value3b"]]
#=> ["Label4", ["Value4"]]
```

**Using a Little XPath**:

```
doc.css('dt').each do |dt|
  dds = dt.xpath('following-sibling::*').chunk{ |n| n.name }.first.last
  p [dt.text,dds.map(&:text)]
end
#=> ["Label1", ["Value1"]]
#=> ["Label2", ["Value2"]]
#=> ["Label3", ["Value3a", "Value3b"]]
#=> ["Label4", ["Value4"]]
```

**Using Lotsa XPath**:

```
doc.css('dt').each do |dt|
  ct = dt.xpath('count(following-sibling::dt)')
  dds = dt.xpath("following-sibling::dd[count(following-sibling::dt)=#{ct}]")
  p [dt.text,dds.map(&:text)]
end
#=> ["Label1", ["Value1"]]
#=> ["Label2", ["Value2"]]
#=> ["Label3", ["Value3a", "Value3b"]]
#=> ["Label4", ["Value4"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the other answer here is an inefficient way of doing the same thing.

```
require 'nokogiri'
a = Nokogiri::HTML('<div id="first"><dt>Label1</dt><dd>Value1</dd><dt>Label2</dt><dd>Value2</dd></div>')

dt = []
dd = []

a.css("#first").each do |item|
  item.css("dt").each {|t| dt << t.text}
  item.css("dd").each {|t| dd << t.text}
end

dt.each_index do |i|
  puts dt[i] + ': ' + dd[i]
end
```

In css to reference the ID you need to put the # symbol before. For a class it's the . symbol.

Comment: Note that since `"#first"` can only ever match one element, what you have is equivalent (but worse) than: `item = a.at_css("#first")`. Using `each` on the outside is entirely superfluous.

Comment: Also, note that this answer assumes that there is always exactly a 1-1 pairing between `<dt>` and a `<dd>`. Although this is true for the original question markup, it may not always be true in real-world markup. Finally, with iterating two paired arrays, you might consider using `dt.zip(dd).each{ |dt,dd| ... }` instead of `each_with_index`.