# How do I use Nokogiri to capture consecutive elements between sibling tags?

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I have something like the following HTML that represents multiple choice questions. The pattern is normally `<p>` tag (the question), followed by and `<ol>` and four `<li>`s (the answer choices). However, only occasionaly, a question is more than one `<p>` tag long.

```
<ol />
<p class="Question-Stem">Which choice is best?</p>
<ol>
  <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
  <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
  <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
  <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
</ol>
<ol />
<p class="Question-Stem">Which choice is best?</p>
<p class="Indented-Sentence">more text</p>
<p class="Question-Stem">more text</p>
<ol>
  <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
  <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
  <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
  <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
</ol>
<ol />
<p class="Question-Stem">null</p>
<ol>
  <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
  <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
  <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
  <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
</ol>
```

I am parsing the questions into an array of hashes, one hash per question

```
questions_array = []

questions_doc.css('p.Question-Stem').each do |p|
  # skip this iteration if the previous tag is not an ol tag 
  # (i.e. it's not the beginning of the stem)
  next if p.previous_element.name != "ol"
  question = { :stem => "", :answer_choices => [] }
  p.inner_html == "null" ? question[:stem] = "" : question[:stem] = p.inner_html
  p.next_element.element_children.each do |child|
    question[:answer_choices] << child.inner_html
  end
  questions_array << question
end
```

This is parsing exactly as I would like *except* for those few cases where the question stem is three `p` tags in a row. In those cases, I want the html of **all three tags** together to get pushed into `question[:stem]`. Any ideas how to achieve that?
I have already read [How to parse consecutive tags with Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482739/how-to-parse-consecutive-tags-with-nokogiri) but didn't find the solutions applicable to this case.

Answer (score 1):

Working with the document using declarative selectors only (css, xpath) is good when your document has a regular structure.

If it doesn't, and you have to introduce explicit control flow (loops, conditionals etc), then you might need to go imperative and traverse the document tree explicitly, node by node.

In this case, it could be something quite straightforward, like the following:

1. find the 1st question node,
2. check the next sibling

- if it is another `p` node - add its content to the current question being parsed,
- otherwise, if it is `ol` node, then complete the current question and extract the answers for it,
- otherwise, if it is something else, skip it (like empty text nodes for newlines that nokogiri recognizes)

3. repeat 2 while the next sibling exists

The naive (and quite fragile and dirty) implementation of this algorithm:

```rb
def extract_questions(doc)
  questions = []
  current_node = doc.xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'Question-Stem')]").first
  current_question = [current_node&.text].compact

  loop do
    current_node = current_node&.next_sibling
    break if current_node.nil?

    case current_node.name
    when "p"
      current_question << current_node.text
    when "ol"
      answers = current_node.children.select { |c| c.name == "li" }.map(&:text)
      questions << { stem: current_question.join("\n"), answer_choices: answers}
      current_question = []
    end  
  end

  questions
end
```

Now

```rb
html = <<~HTML
  <p class="Question-Stem">Which choice is best?</p>
  <ol>
    <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
    <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
    <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
    <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
  </ol>
  <p class="Question-Stem">Which choice is best?</p>
  <p class="Indented-Sentence">more text</p>
  <p class="Question-Stem">more text</p>
  <ol>
    <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
    <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
    <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
    <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
  </ol>
  <p class="Question-Stem">null</p>
  <ol>
    <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
    <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
    <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
    <li class="Answer-Choice">text</li>
  </ol>
HTML

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

extract_questions(doc) # => [{:stem=>"Which choice is best?", :answer_choices=>["text", "text", "text", "text"]},{:stem=>"Which choice is best?\nmore text\nmore text", :answer_choices=>["text", "text", "text", "text"]},{:stem=>"null", :answer_choices=>["text", "text", "text", "text"]}]
```

Comment: Yes! This works great. Except there are a bunch of self-closing `<ol />` tags that mess up the loop, so inside `case "ol"` I need to add `next if current_node.children.empty?`