# XPath to find all following siblings up until the next sibling of a particular type

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

Given this XML/HTML:

```xml
<dl>
  <dt>Label1</dt><dd>Value1</dd>
  <dt>Label2</dt><dd>Value2</dd>
  <dt>Label3</dt><dd>Value3a</dd><dd>Value3b</dd>
  <dt>Label4</dt><dd>Value4</dd>
</dl>
```

I want to find all `<dt>` and then, for each, find the following `<dd>` up until the next `<dt>`.

Using Ruby's [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) I am able to accomplish this like so:

```ruby
dl.xpath('dt').each do |dt|
  ct  = dt.xpath('count(following-sibling::dt)')
  dds = dt.xpath("following-sibling::dd[count(following-sibling::dt)=#{ct}]")
  puts "#{dt.text}: #{dds.map(&:text).join(', ')}"
end
#=> Label1: Value1
#=> Label2: Value2
#=> Label3: Value3a, Value3b
#=> Label4: Value4
```

However, as you can see I'm creating a variable in Ruby and then composing an XPath using it. How can I write a single XPath expression that does the equivalent?

I guessed at:

```
following-sibling::dd[count(following-sibling::dt)=count(self/following-sibling::dt)]
```

but apparently I don't understand what `self` means there.

*This question is similar to [XPath : select all following siblings until another sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161766/xpath-select-all-following-siblings-until-another-sibling) except there is no unique identifier for the 'stop' node.*

*This question is almost the same as [xpath to find all following sibling adjacent nodes up til another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888916/xpath-to-find-all-following-sibling-adjacent-nodes-up-til-another-type) except that I'm asking for an XPath-only solution.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
dl.xpath('dt').each_with_index do |dt, i|
  dds = dt.xpath("following-sibling::dd[not(../dt[#{i + 2}]) or " +
                     "following-sibling::dt[1]=../dt[#{i + 2}]]")
  puts "#{dt.text}: #{dds.map(&:text).join(', ')}"
end
```

This relies on a *value* comparison of `dt` elements and will fail when there are duplicates. The following (much more complicated) expression does not depend on unique `dt` values:

```
following-sibling::dd[not(../dt[$n]) or 
    (following-sibling::dt[1] and count(following-sibling::dt[1]|../dt[$n])=1)]
```

**Note:** Your use of `self` fails because you're not properly using it as an axis (`self::`). Also, `self` always contains just the context node, so it would refer to each `dd` inspected by the expression, not back to the original `dt`

Comment: Thanks; that's what I feared about the `self::` axis. +1 for the suggestion, but this is still relying upon Ruby to craft the expression, so no acceptance.

Comment: @Phrogz - I guess I breezed right past that requirement. Unfortunately, I don't think it's *possible*, because you need to refer back to the `dt` element that you're operating on, but all knowledge of which `dt` you're operating on is contained in Ruby. How is the expression supposed to reference this context unless you interpolate a reference to it?

Comment: I'm not sure, and I could accept it if it was not possible. The knowledge of the `dt` isn't just in Ruby, though; it's also the context node when the XPath expression starts. I had originally hoped to be able to create a complex XPath expression with variables such as: `let $ct = count(following-sibling::dt); following-sibling::dd[count(following-sibling::dt)=$ct]` but had no luck. If there's no way to reference the original context later in the expression this may not be possible...or perhaps there's another approach entirely to the problem of finding all `dd` up until the next `dt`.

Comment: @Phrogz - The problem is that the context node changes throughout the expression (e.g. in each location step or in nested predicates).

Comment: Also, I don't think Nokogiri supports XPath 2.0.

Comment: You are correct, it does not support XPath 2.0. (Is that what the `let` variable syntax I was using is?)

Comment: @Phrogz -  No, I was just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting question. Most of the problems were already mentioned in @lwburk's answer and in its comments. Just to open up a bit more the complexity hidden in this question for a random reader, my answer is probably more elaborate or more verbose than OP needed.

#### Features of XPath 1.0 related to this problem

In XPath each step, and each node in the set of selected nodes, work independently. This means that

1. a subexpression has no generic way to access data that was computed in a previous subexpression or share data computed in this subexpression to other subexpressions
2. a node has no generic way to refer to a node that was used as a context node in a previous subexpression
3. a node has no generic way to refer to other nodes that are currently selected.
4. if everyone of the selected nodes must be compared to a same certain node, then that node must be uniquely definable in a way that is common to all selected nodes

(Well, in fact I'm not 100% sure if that list is absolutely correct in every case. If anyone has better knowledge of the quirks of XPath, please comment or correct this answer by editing it.)

Despite the lack of generic solutions some of these restrictions can be overcome if there is proper knowledge of the document structure, and/or the axis used previously can be "reverted" with another axis that serves as a backlink i.e. matches only nodes that were used as context node in the previous expression. A common example of this is when a `parent` axis is used after first using a `child` axis (the opposite case, from child to parent, is not uniquely revertible without additional information). In such cases, the information from previous steps is more precisely recreated at a later step (instead of accessing previously known information).

Unfortunately in this case I couldn't come up with any other solution to refer to previously known nodes except using XPath variables (that needs to be defined beforehand).

XPath specifies a syntax for referring a variable but it does not specify syntax for defining variables, the way how to define variables depends on the environment where XPath is used. Actually since the recommendation states that "The variable bindings used to evaluate a subexpression are always the same as those used to evaluate the containing expression", you could also claim that XPath explicitly forbids defining variables inside an XPath expression.

#### Problem reformulated

In your question the problem would be, when given a `<dt>`, to identify the following `<dd>` elements or the initially given node after the context node has been switched. Identifying the originally given `<dt>` is crucial since for each node in the node-set to be filtered, the predicate expression is evaluated with that node as the context node; so one cannot refer to the original `<dt>` in a predicate, if there is no way to identify it after the context has changed. The same applies to `<dd>` elements that are following siblings of the given `<dt>`.

If you are using variables, one could debate is there a major difference between 1) using XPath variable syntax and a Nokogiri specific way to declare that variable or 2) using Nokogiri extended XPath syntax that allows you to use Ruby variables in an XPath expression. In both cases the variable is defined in environment specific way and the meaning of the XPath is clear only if the definition of the variable is also available. Similar case can be seen with XSLT where in some cases you could make a choice between 1) defining a variable with `<xsl:variable>` prior to using your XPath expression or 2) using `current()` (inside your XPath expression) which is an XSLT extension.

#### Solution using nodeset variables and Kaysian method

You can select all the `<dd>` elements following the *current* `<dt>` element with `following-sibling::dd` (set A). Also you can select all the `<dd>` elements following the *next* `<dt>` element with `following-sibling::dt[1]/following-sibling::dd` (set B). Now a set difference `A\B` leaves the `<dd>` elements you actually wanted (elements that are in set A but not in set B). If variable `$setA` contains nodeset A and variable `$setB` contains nodeset B, the set difference can be obtained with (a modification of) Kaysian technique:

```
dds = $setA[count(.|$setB) != count($setB)]
```

#### A simple workaround without any variables

Currently your method is to select all the `<dt>` elements and then try to couple the value of each such element with values of corresponding `<dd>` elements in a single operation. Would it be possible to convert that coupling logic to work the other way round? So you would first select all `<dd>` elements and then for each `<dd>` find the corresponding `<dt>`. This would mean that you end up accessing same `<dt>` elements several times and with every operation you add only one new `<dd>` value. This could affect performance and the Ruby code could be more complicated.

The good side is the simplicity of the required XPath. When given a `<dd>` element, finding the corresponding `<dt>` is amazingly simple: `preceding-sibling::dt[1]`

As applied to your current Ruby code

```
dl.xpath('dd').each do |dd|
  dt = dd.xpath("preceding-sibling::dt[1]")
  ## Insert new Ruby magic here ##
end
```